# Display characters instead of unicode numbers in PyCharm watch window

Tags: unicode, utf-8, pycharm, chinese-locale

The problem I have can be re-produced by pasting this code into PyCharm:

```
chinese = [u'这', u'是', u'一', u'些', u'中', u'文']
print chinese
```

When you set a breakpoint at the `print` line and start debugging, you could see tha the variable `chinese` in the watch window is displayed as

```
[u'\u8fd9', u'\u662f', u'\u4e00', u'\u4e9b', u'\u4e2d', u'\u6587']`
```

However, I expect it to be

```
[u'这', u'是', u'一', u'些', u'中', u'文']
```

Unless I double click this variable, it does not show the characters directly.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like a bug, please submit an issue to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: Have you ever solved it?